# Mercurial: Build script creates 2nd line when tagging the tip

Tags: mercurial, build-automation, versioning

I've hunted SO for other Mercurial posts relating to tags and build scripts but I didn't find the particular issue I'm seeing.

I've been using a bitbucket.org hosted Mercurial server for a few weeks.  My workflow is to write code, push to the local repo then push to bitbucket.  I'm the only contributor in my project and I only use one machine to code so I haven't had any tricky merges or conflicts to resolve yet.  I use TortoiseHg to perform checkins and code reviews.

Today I wrote a script to automate my builds but I ran into a problem.  I use c:\dev for coding and I use c:\build as the root folder for the build process.

My process is:
1) Get the latest code -- clone the repo or get latest if it is already cloned
2) Version the code
3) Build the code
4) Tag the local repo
5) Push the tag to bitbucket.org

I'm using a simple batch program:

```
REM variable assignment, versioning, and error checking are excluded from this snippet

ECHO Getting code from remote repository...
IF EXIST .\%localrepo% (
    ECHO Pulling latest
    hg pull %localrepo%
) else (
    ECHO Cloning repository
    hg clone %remoterepo%
)
ECHO Done retrieving code.

ECHO Building code...
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" %solution% /build %solutionconfig%
ECHO Building complete.

cd %localrepo%
hg tag %version%
hg push
cd ..
```

This script seemed to achieve all of my goals and everything was going well until I went back to TortoiseHg and noticed that the revision Graph now shows two lines -- one for my c:\dev coding and another for the tag created by the build script in c:\build.

I don't have enough reputation to embed an image, but this link will show a screenshot of the revision history reported by TortoiseHg - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWWB6.png

With a bit of struggle, I merged the new line (revision 38) back to the original (revision 39), but when I ran the build script again (revision 40) the new tag continued on the 2nd line.  I tried to commit a change from the dev repository, but that commit was aborted due to "push creates note remote head".

I feel like I'm maybe doing something fundamentally wrong in my build script.  Any advice or topics I need to read up on?  I failed to find any non-MSBuild scripting solutions relating to Mercurial code servers. I am not tied to using a batch script for any reason -- it was just a simple and free solution that I expected to be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg clone` automatically updates your working directory to the tip of the default branch, but `hg pull` does not.  Use `hg pull -u` to update the the head of your current branch after a pull.